# Stack Navigation Produces 2 headers

Tags: android, css, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently developing an app. This is my first time with React-native. Basically, I'm having [this](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/614) issue

I have three navigation options. 
First of my navigation is my main and home screen. It has `headerMode : 'none'`

Second one is the drawer. I don't want header in the drawer and I've created it manually. It has `headerMode : 'none'`

From this drawer, I'm moving to other pages(lets say it Page A), which should have headers. This pages have `headerMode: 'screen'` in their navigationOptions.

My issue is, when I navigate from login page to Page A, it has header, but this header doesn't have back button.

If I change my first navigation's headermode from null to screen, I have header(fully functioning with back button) but I also have the second header too. If I couldn't tell my problem correctly, or you couldn't understand it, please look at the link above.

---

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it with removing sublevel navigation and removing `{headerMode: 'null'}` from Stacknavigators option. I manually added `header:null` to the each screen.
Code is like below:

```
> const TopLevelNav = StackNavigator({  
>              Home: { screen: HomeScreen,
>                      navigationOptions :{header: null } },   
>              Main: { screen: MyApp,       
>                      navigationOptions :{header: null } },    
>              SubNavigation : {screen: Screen1},
>              Screen2: {screen: Screen2},
>       }, 
>//{headerMode: 'none'}  
);
```